# Issues with my Verilog Simulation -x's and z's in signals

Tags: verilog, hardware, simulation, hdl

I have a project, in which I have to implement a list processor that computes the squared-norm of a complex vector.

EDITED:
My code is compiling, and the simulation is working, and I corrected all the connections, so my input signals are reading values. But I am having some trouble with the "start" signal. In the testbench I set it to 0. then to 1 but for some reason it remains 0. Anyone know why a signal would usually stay 0 even though it was assigned to a particula value in the test bench??

I'm still amateurish in verilog, so I'm not sure what I did wrong. I've been tracking every module used, checked if there were errors in instantiating, but I'm missing something, silly or fundamental. I just have no idea what it is.

Here is the code: the total modules are control, memory, datapath, testbench and VNLP (aka the module that computes the squared-norm).

```
module control (output reg [7:0] counter, output reg add1_sel, add2_sel, before_sel, next_sel, acc_sel, A1_sel, A2_sel, load_before, load_next, load_acc, done_op, input clk, start_op);
wire [9:0] one, zero, before, next;
//reg [7:0] counter;
reg [1 : 0] state, next_state; 
parameter Start=0, Compute=1, GetNext=2, Done=3;
reg counter_start, counter_incr;
assign one=before;
assign zero=next;



always@(posedge clk) begin
        if (start_op) state<=Start;
        else  state<=next_state;
end

always@(posedge clk) begin
if (counter_start ==1)
    counter<=0;
else if(counter_incr==1)
    counter<=counter+1;
end






always@(state, start_op, zero, one) begin
load_acc=0;
next_sel=0; 
before_sel=0; 
A1_sel=0; 
A2_sel=0; 
load_next=0; 
load_before=0; 
done_op=0;
acc_sel=0;
add1_sel=0;
add2_sel=0;
counter_incr=0;
counter_start=0;


case(state)

Start: 
        begin
        next_sel=0;
        before_sel=0;
        load_next=1;
        load_before=1;
        acc_sel=0;
        load_acc=1;
counter_start=1;
add1_sel=0;
add2_sel=0;
        //load_M1=0;
        //load_M2=0;
        done_op=0;
        if (start_op ==0)   next_state=Compute;
        //else next_state=Start;
    end


Compute:
    begin
        counter_start=0;
        next_sel=1;
        before_sel=1;
        load_next=0;
        load_before=0;
        A1_sel=1;
        A2_sel=1;
add1_sel=1;
add2_sel=1;
        //load_M1=1;
        //load_M2=1;
        load_acc=1;
        acc_sel=1;
        done_op=0;
        if (start_op ==0) next_state=GetNext;
        //else next_state=Start;
    end

GetNext:
    begin
        load_next=1;
        load_before=1;
        A1_sel=0;
        A2_sel=0;
        load_acc=0; 
        done_op=0;
        if (start_op ==0) begin
            if (zero==0 || one==1) next_state= Done;
            else if (!start_op && zero!=0 && one!=1) begin next_state=Compute; counter_incr=1; end
        end
    end

Done:
    begin
        done_op=1;
        load_acc=0; counter_incr=0;
        if (start_op ==1) next_state=Start;
        //else next_state=Done;
    end

default: next_state= Start; 

endcase


end


endmodule





module memory (D1, D2, A1, A2);
parameter word_size=10;
parameter address_size=9;
parameter memory_size= 512;
reg [9:0] memory [memory_size-1:0]; 
output reg [word_size-1:0] D1;
output reg [word_size-1:0] D2;
input [address_size-1:0] A1;
input [address_size-1:0] A2;
always@(*) begin
         D1=memory[A1];
        D2=memory[A2];
end
endmodule 


module VNLP (
output reg[27: 0] norm2, output reg[7:0] len, output reg Done, input reg done_op, output reg [8:0] A1, A2, input [7:0] counter, 
input [9:0] D1, D2, output reg [9:0] Next, Before, output  reg [27:0] Accumulator,
 input add1_sel, add2_sel, before_sel, next_sel, acc_sel, A1_sel, A2_sel, load_before, load_next, load_acc,clk, start_op);

reg [19:0] adder1, adder2;
wire [20:0] sum_add;
reg [27:0] acc;
reg [9:0] before, next;
reg [8:0] a1, a2;

reg [19:0] d1, d2;

//assign d1= D1*D1;
//assign d2=D2*D2;


assign sum_add= adder1 + adder2;


always@(*) begin

if (add2_sel) begin adder2=D2*D2; end
else adder2=20'b0;

if (add1_sel) adder1=D1*D1;
else adder1=20'b0;



if (before_sel) before=D2;
else before=10'b0;


if (next_sel) next=D1;
else next=10'b0;


if (acc_sel) acc=sum_add+ Accumulator;
else acc=28'b0;


if (A1_sel) A1<=Next+ 2'b10;
else A1<=Next;


if (A2_sel) A2<=Before+ 2'b10;
else A2<=Before;


if (done_op) begin 
    norm2<= Accumulator;
    len=counter;
    Done=1;
    end
    else begin 
        norm2<=28'b0;
        len<=8'b0;
        Done<=0;
        end
end


always@(posedge clk) begin
    if (load_before) Before<= before;
end

always@(posedge clk) begin
    if (load_next) Next<= next;
end

always@(posedge clk) begin
    if (load_acc) Accumulator<= acc;
end



endmodule





module Datapath (
input start_op, clk,
output Done,
output [7:0] len,
output [27:0] norm2);

wire [8:0] A1, A2;
wire [9:0] D1, D2;


wire done_op;
wire [7:0] counter;
wire  [9:0] Next, Before;
wire [27:0] Accumulator;
wire add1_sel, add2_sel, before_sel, next_sel, acc_sel, A1_sel, A2_sel, load_before, load_next, load_acc;




VNLP VNLP(norm2, len, Done, done_op, A1, A2, counter, D1, D2, Next, Before,Accumulator, 
add1_sel, add2_sel, before_sel, next_sel, acc_sel, A1_sel, A2_sel,
 load_before, load_next, load_acc,clk, start_op);

memory M1 (D1, D2, A1, A2);

control control (counter,add1_sel, add2_sel, before_sel, next_sel, acc_sel, A1_sel, A2_sel, load_before, load_next, load_acc, done_op, clk, start_op);



endmodule


module Datapath_tb;


reg start_op, clk;
wire Done;
wire [7:0] len;
wire [27:0] norm2;
reg[8:0] k;


wire[9:0]  word0,word1,word2,word3,
word4,word5,word6,word7,
word8,word9,word10,word11,
word12,word13,word14,word15, 
word16,word17,word18,word19,
word20, word21,word22,word23,
word24,word25,word26,word27, 
word28,word29,word30,word31,
word32, word33,word34,word35,
word36,word37,word38,word39; 


Datapath Datapath (
start_op, clk,
Done,
len,
norm2);

assign      word0 = Datapath.M1.memory[0]; 
assign      word1 = Datapath.M1.memory[1]; 


assign      word2 = Datapath.M1.memory[2]; 
assign      word3 = Datapath.M1.memory[3]; 
assign      word4 = Datapath.M1.memory[5]; 
assign      word5 = Datapath.M1.memory[6]; 
assign      word6 = Datapath.M1.memory[7]; 
assign      word7 = Datapath.M1.memory[8]; 
assign      word8 = Datapath.M1.memory[11]; 
assign      word9 = Datapath.M1.memory[12]; 
assign      word10 = Datapath.M1.memory[13]; 
assign      word11 = Datapath.M1.memory[14]; 
assign      word12 = Datapath.M1.memory[17]; 
assign      word13 = Datapath.M1.memory[18]; 
assign      word14 = Datapath.M1.memory[19]; 
assign      word15 = Datapath.M1.memory[20]; 
assign      word16 = Datapath.M1.memory[22]; 
assign      word17 = Datapath.M1.memory[23]; 
assign      word18 = Datapath.M1.memory[24]; 
assign      word19 = Datapath.M1.memory[25]; 
assign      word20 = Datapath.M1.memory[28]; 
assign      word21 = Datapath.M1.memory[29]; 
assign      word22 = Datapath.M1.memory[30]; 
assign      word23 = Datapath.M1.memory[31]; 
assign      word24 = Datapath.M1.memory[33]; 
assign      word25 = Datapath.M1.memory[34]; 
assign      word26 = Datapath.M1.memory[35]; 
assign      word27 = Datapath.M1.memory[36]; 
assign      word28 = Datapath.M1.memory[39]; 
assign      word29 = Datapath.M1.memory[40]; 
assign      word30 = Datapath.M1.memory[41]; 
assign      word31 = Datapath.M1.memory[42]; 
assign      word32 = Datapath.M1.memory[44]; 
assign      word33 = Datapath.M1.memory[45]; 
assign      word34 = Datapath.M1.memory[46]; 
assign      word35 = Datapath.M1.memory[47]; 
assign      word36 = Datapath.M1.memory[49]; 
assign      word37 = Datapath.M1.memory[50]; 
assign      word38 = Datapath.M1.memory[51]; 
assign      word39 = Datapath.M1.memory[52]; 


//VNLP VNLP(norm2, len, done, A1, A2, counter, D1, D2, Next, Before,Accumulator, add1_sel, add2_sel, before_sel, next_sel, acc_sel, A1_sel, A2_sel, load_before, load_next, load_acc,clk, start);


//Flush memory
initial
begin: Flush
start_op=0; clk=0; 
for (k=0; k<=52; k=k+1) Datapath.M1.memory[k] = 0; 
end

initial
begin: Load
#5
  #5 start_op=1; #5 start_op=0;
Datapath.M1.memory[0] = 49; 
Datapath.M1.memory[1] = 34; 
Datapath.M1.memory[2] = -33;                  
Datapath.M1.memory[3] = 23; 
Datapath.M1.memory[5] = 17 ;
Datapath.M1.memory[6]=40; 
Datapath.M1.memory[7] = 19;
Datapath.M1.memory[8]=102; 
Datapath.M1.memory[11] = 22;
Datapath.M1.memory[12]=18; 
Datapath.M1.memory[13] = 25; 
Datapath.M1.memory[14] = -93;         
Datapath.M1.memory[17]=11; 
Datapath.M1.memory[18] = 6; 
Datapath.M1.memory[19] = 8 ;
Datapath.M1.memory[20]=90; 
Datapath.M1.memory[22] = 33; 
Datapath.M1.memory[23] = 12; 
Datapath.M1.memory[24] = 31; 
Datapath.M1.memory[25] = 32; 
Datapath.M1.memory[28] = 102; 
Datapath.M1.memory[29] = 240; 

Datapath.M1.memory[30]=47; 
Datapath.M1.memory[31] = -11; 
Datapath.M1.memory[33] = 0;         
Datapath.M1.memory[34]=23; 
Datapath.M1.memory[35] = 25; 
Datapath.M1.memory[36] = 88;
Datapath.M1.memory[39]=5; 
Datapath.M1.memory[40] = 50; 
Datapath.M1.memory[41] = 56; 
Datapath.M1.memory[42] = 48; 
Datapath.M1.memory[44] = 56; 
Datapath.M1.memory[45] = 88; 
Datapath.M1.memory[46] = 112; 

Datapath.M1.memory[47] = 69; 
Datapath.M1.memory[49] = 39; 
Datapath.M1.memory[50] = 1; 
Datapath.M1.memory[51] = 101; 
Datapath.M1.memory[52] = 63; 

end


always forever #5 clk=~clk;

endmodule
```

And this is an idea of the architecture if that helps:

[Architecture Schematic for processor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IiJ4D.png)

Comment: I think so... but in any case here is the entire code:

Answer (score 0):

Usually you get Z's on inputs because you have not connected up things correctly. Check your inputs for missing connections or typos before trying to diagnose the outputs.

Comment: I checked my inputs. I don't think there's anything missing (besides, I would've gotten an error wouldn't I?). Even the start is not behaving the way I'm telling it to. Only the clock acts normally.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are not connecting the control module in the top level (datapath module of your code). There are initiations of VNLP and memory modules but not the control module. You have assigned the same names to inputs of the VNLP and the outputs of control module, however this does not ensure that they are connected. Thus, control module is not used in your design and this is probably the reason why the inputs and outputs are not working.